# Automatic shutdown

Tags: macos, terminal, shutdown

While trying to cancel an automatic shutdown, I used the following inTerminal:

```
* * * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Most probably I entered it within:

```
crontab -e
```

Hoping that by not giving any time the shutdown would not happen... Big mistake!
Now the computer does not turn on any more.

Do you have any suggestion to fix that in Recovery Mode or Single-User Mode?

Comment: I love the logic: I don't want it to shutdown at a specific time anymore, so I'll set it to shutdown all the time.

Comment: Try booting to safe mode.

Comment: This line, as you copied it in your original question cannot do any damage exept an error message, typically: `bash: command not found: Applications`.Where exactly did you enter this line? Were you `root` at this time?

Comment: @danielAzuelos It’s almost certain Sbor was in `crontab -e` or editing the cron file and in their panic to post for help didn’t think through the details we’d need to help them. I expect an edit soon from them to clarify what precisely they did if my answer doesn’t help them self rescue. As you point out, they had to do lots of things in terminal before pasting/typing `* * * * * /sbin/shutdown`

Comment: @bmike: thank you I made the same hypothesis leading to such a deadful `shutdown loop`. I tried to add an easier method.

Comment: Thanks all! Booting in safe mode disnt work; in single-user mode I only had a “read only” mode. I went the easiest way and used time machine backup.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was lacking a key detail . Shame on me.

Answer (score 3):

If I guess correctly you probably entered the line:

```
* * * * * /sbin/shutdown
```

in the `root` crontab with the command `crontab -e` when in priviledged mode (running as `root`).

The simplest way to get out of this `shutdown` **every minute** is as follows:

1. Boot your Mac in **single-user** mode:
   immediatly after powering it on, hold on <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> until you get white text on a black screen.
2. Once you see the shell prompt, beware: you are `root`, everything you type might destroy your system, enter the following command:

   ```
   /sbin/mount -uw /
   ```

   (== remount the `/` filesystem in write mode) so as to be able to modify the `root` crontab  which is on the `/` filesystem

   ```
   /usr/bin/crontab -e
   ```

   which will let you edit your `root` crontab file, go to the line containing exactly (it might be the uniq line):

   ```
   * * * * * /sbin/shutdown
   ```

   and an editor should open (from memory, it should be `vi` but
   I'm only 50% sure) delete it (in `vi`: `dd`), save your file and exit(in `vi`: `:wq`).
3. Type `/sbin/reboot` to restart your system without the deadful `crontab` line.

Comment: Do you need to mount the filesystem write `mount -uw /` or has something changed?

Comment: Thank you. I improved my answer with your key detail !

Answer (score 1):

Yes - boot to recovery HD or OS and then look for the terminal utility in the menu. You will be able to edit the crontab file to remove that entry and chill out the over active `shutdown` process.

Even easier would be to boot your Mac in target disk mode and edit the file from another Mac that’s running and can connect to your storage as if it’s an external drive.

Worst case, you can restore from a backup before the system got the wrong instructions you didn’t realize would be painful. There’s going to be no data loss since you can’t work on anything after this change was made. Time Machine even might have a local backup you can roll back, so be sure to check that if you can’t fix things in recovery mode.